# Асинхронный Tcp клиент-сервер

Tags: c#, асинхронность, tcp

Помогите, пожалуйста, с пониманием асинхронной реализации Tcp клиент-сервера. Читал статьи на MDSN, гуглил. Но эта куча BeginWrite, BeginRead, коллбэков просто выносит мозг.

1. Правда ли то, что несмотря на задающийся размер буфера в BeginRead, могут прийти меньше или больше данных? И как тогда с этим справляться?
2. Как вообще эффективно реализовать простейший клиент-сервер, если первыми двумя байтами идет "код действия", а затем произвольное кол-во байт, в которых содержатся строки, int, ushort и т.д., если часть пакета может где-то застрять или прийти излишек?

С синхронной реализацией все ок, но ест много ЦП т.к. цикл while.

Comment: Не-не, никаких `BeginRead`. Модные пацаны делают сейчас всё через `async`/`await`.

Курите вот [этот](https://gist.github.com/jamesmanning/2622054) пример.

Comment: По поводу данных, разумеется, может прийти сколько угодно. Вы должны старательно вычитывать данные до тех пор, пока не придёт нужное количество. Вот [тут](/questions/306548/) есть пример. Его можно и под сервер переделать.

Comment: (Спасибо)
Т.е. если даже в async методе будет долгая операция, то приложение не заблокируется? Отлично.
Вот только принимать новые подключения на сервере, похоже, все-же лучше через BeginAcceptTcpClient, т.к. при использовании awake надо использовать цикл, за что вроде-как ругают :)

Comment: @rinart73, пихать в цикл метод ожидания клиента (AcceptTcpClientAsync, например)

Comment: @rinart73: Почему же, никаких колбэков не нужно.

Сервер слушает входящие сообщения, и при приходе запускает на обработку. Обработка бежит параллельно, а сервер продолжает слушать дальше в цикле (`AcceptTcpClientAsync()` и дальше). Получится что-то такое:

    var tcpListener = TcpListener.Create(1234);
    tcpListener.Start();
    while(true)
    {
        var tcpClient = await tcpListener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
        processClientTearOff(tcpClient); // await не нужен
    }

    async Task processClientTearOff(TcpClient client)
    {
       ...

Comment: Да, но то же придется делать и с принимаемыми сообщениями. И получается дикая нагрузка на ЦП :( Или я что-то не понимаю

Comment: Ок. Но вот в чем дело:
async Task ClientHandler(TcpClient c)
{
  Clients.Add(new Client(c););
}
На что мне IDE говорит, что т.к. метод не имеет внутри await-ов, то будет исполняться синхронно. Или я чего опять туплю.
У меня просто жизненно необходимо для каждого клиента создавать свой объект т.к. данных там масса.

Comment: @rinart73: Вам надо просто

    Task processClientTearOff(TcpClient client) // без async
    {
        using (var client = new Client(c))
            return client.ProcessAsync();
    }

    class Client : IDisposable
    {
        NetworkStream s; // = client.GetStream()
        public async Task ProcessAsync()
        {
            var actionBuffer = await ReadFromStreamAsync(s, 2);
            var action = (ActionEnum)BitConverter.ToInt16(actionBuffer, 0);
            ...

Comment: @rinart73: подправил предыдущий пример: там нужен `await`, без него `Dispose` вызовется раньше времени.

Comment: @rinart73: `ReadFromStreamAsync` — это [отсюда](/questions/306548/). А вы уверены, что вам не нужен `Dispose`? Вы ж должны где-то закрыть `NetworkStream`.

Если всё работает, перенесу код в ответ :)

Comment: Главные принципы я понял. А с остальным буду разбираться попозже

Comment: @rinart73: Отлично! Удачи вам. Если что, задавайте вопросы тут, постараемся ответить.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Сейчас принято делать всю асинхронность через `async`/`await`. Вот несколько примеров: [[1]](https://gist.github.com/jamesmanning/2622054), [[2]](/questions/306548/), я надёргаю кусков из них.

Сервер слушает входящие сообщения, и при приходе запускает на обработку. Обработка бежит параллельно, а сервер продолжает слушать дальше в цикле (`AcceptTcpClientAsync()` и дальше). Получится что-то такое:

Весь сервер:

```
void RunServer()
{
    var tcpListener = TcpListener.Create(<порт>);
    tcpListener.Start();
    while (true) // тут какое-то разумное условие выхода
    {
        var tcpClient = await tcpListener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
        processClientTearOff(tcpClient); // await не нужен
    }
}

async Task processClientTearOff(TcpClient c)
{
    using (var client = new Client(c))
        await client.ProcessAsync();
}
```

Обработчик одного клиентского запроса:

```
class Client : IDisposable
{
    NetworkStream s;

    public Client(TcpClient c)
    {
        s = client.GetStream();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        s.Dispose();
    }

    async Task<byte[]> ReadFromStreamAsync(int nbytes)
    {
        var buf = new byte[nbytes];
        var readpos = 0;
        while (readpos < nbytes)
            readpos += await s.ReadAsync(buf, readpos, nbytes - readpos);
        return buf;
    }

    public async Task ProcessAsync()
    {
        var actionBuffer = await ReadFromStreamAsync(2);
        var action = (ActionEnum)BitConverter.ToInt16(actionBuffer, 0);
        switch (action)
        {
            // логика в зависимости от кода команды
        }
    }
}
```

Если сервер надо останавливать, вам придётся дождаться окончания работы запущенных `Task`'ов:

```
async void RunServer()
{
    var tcpListener = TcpListener.Create(<порт>);
    tcpListener.Start();
    while (можно продолжать)
    {
        var tcpClient = await tcpListener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
        processClient(tcpClient); // await не нужен
    }
    await Task.WaitAll(activeClientTasks.ToList()); // нужна копия
}

HashSet<Task> activeClientTasks = new HashSet<Task>();
async Task processClient(TcpClient c)
{
    using (var client = new Client(c))
    {
        Task task = null;
        try
        {
            task = client.ProcessAsync();
            activeClientTasks.Add(task);
            await task;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (task != null)
                activeClientTasks.Remove(task);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Вот реализация таймаута (набросал, код не запускал, возможны ошибки):

```
async Task<byte[]> ReadFromStreamAsync(int nbytes, CancellationToken ct)
{
    var buf = new byte[nbytes];
    var readpos = 0;
    while (readpos < nbytes)
        readpos += await s.ReadAsync(buf, readpos, nbytes - readpos, ct);
    return buf;
}

async Task<string> ReadWithTimeout(int n)
{
    using (var cts = new CancellationTokenSource())
    {
        var readTask = ReadFromStreamAsync(n, cts.Token);
        var timeoutTask = Task.Delay(1000);
        await Task.WhenAny(readTask, timeoutTask);
        if (!readTask.IsCompleted)
        {
            cts.Cancel(); // cancel read task
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            var bytes = readTask.Result;
            return Decode(bytes);
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Обновление:**

Следуя совету @Pavel Mayorov, последний метод можно переписать проще и изящнее:

```
async Task<string> ReadWithTimeout(int n) // (*)
{
    using (var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000)))
    {
        try
        {
            return Decode(await ReadFromStreamAsync(n, cts.Token));
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Обновление:**

К сожалению, несмотря свою изящность, метод с обрывом чтения (я имею в виду вариант, обозначенный `(*)`) не работает [из-за бага в BCL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20132104/276994). Я попробую уточнить код. Кажется, хорошей идеей является закрыть клиент полностью, в соответствии со старой семантикой WinAPI. Вот [сообщение на Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1099042/networkstream-readasync-writeasync-dont-respect-cancellationtoken), проголосуйте за исправление!

---

**Обновление**: Поправил код, руководствуясь предыдущим обновлением. Теперь при обрыве по таймауту возвращается не `null`, а бросается `TimeoutException` (после которого клиент нужно закрывать).

```
async Task<string> ReadWithTimeout(int n)
{
    using (var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000)))
    {
        var token = cts.Token;
        try
        {
            // при обрыве ожидания по токену закрываем клиент
            // с выбросом ObjectDisposedException
            using (token.Register(client.Close))
                return Decode(await ReadFromStreamAsync(n, cts.Token));
        }
        catch (ObjectDisposedException) when (token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            throw new TimeoutException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @VladD, очень изящное и компактное решение. Один вопрос по методу ReadFromStreamAsync. Я попробовал использовать этот метод на клиенте и на сервере. Сначала передается размер сообщения, потом само сообщение, и так в обе стороны. Проблема возникла в зацикливании этого метода если приходит пустой ответ. Ума не приложу как обойти это. На данный момент приходится отсылать короткие ответы.

Comment: @z668: Не совсем понял. Что означает «пустой ответ»? Можете привести пример кода и того, что посылает сервер?

Comment: @VladD, 

сервер: http://pastebin.com/D7TVzLpD

клиент: http://pastebin.com/hjEQT21Y

На сервере посылаю в ответ: SendMessage("Null");
На клиенте указал место зацикливания если сервер ничего не отправляет в ответ.

Comment: @z668: Сразу вопрос: а почему `SendMessage` использует синхронную отправку? Попробуйте переделать его в [`await SendMessageAsync`](http://pastebin.com/TWStMTme). Это раз.

Затем, если негодяй-сервер может не ответить на сообщение, то надо по идее ввести таймаут. То есть, ждать ответа не бесконечно, а лишь какое-то время. Я правильно понимаю, что сервер переслал вам _ненулевую длину_ сообщения, а потом «тянет» с самим сообщением?

Comment: @VladD, нет, сервер просто не отправляет ничего в ответ. Он не посылает длину сообщения. Считайте что он только принимает сообщения от клиента.

"Затем, если негодяй-сервер может не ответить на сообщение, то надо по идее ввести таймаут." - вот тут поподробнее. Каким образом реализовать таймаут? Зацикливание происходит моментально.

Comment: @z668: Вам нужна версия `ReadFromStreamAsync` с возможностью обрыва. Добавил в ответ.

Comment: @VladD, благодарю.

Comment: @z668: Кажется, `CancellationTokenSource` нужно `Dispose`'ить. Добавил в код `using`.

Comment: @VladD, возможно, с вот этим методом код будет выглядеть еще проще: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194678%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Класс, не знал о таком методе. Это новый метод, в документации написано .NET 4.5+. Спасибо! Добавлю в ответ.

Comment: По поводу обновления. Да, вспоминаю, такой баг и правда есть. Но вот в чем дело - прерывание операции чтения оставляет сетевой поток в таком состоянии, в котором его больше невозможно использовать - ведь нам уже не известно, в каком месте этого потока мы находимся! Поэтому единственный корректный способ обработки тайм-аута - это закрытие `TcpClient`.

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Угу, я так и понял. Но это в общем-то баг, основанный на неиспользовании асинхронного IO. Я протестирую код и выложу.

Comment: Я не спорю, это баг. Но даже если бы отмена операции работала - все равно, в случае протокола TCP иначе как закрыть сокет ничего нельзя после прерывания операции сделать.