# Использование Python 3 с C#

Tags: c#, python, .net, clr

Здравствуйте!

Возможно ли интегрировать python 3 и C#?

Существует приложение на c# в которое хочется внести скриптовую функциональность в виду python 3 скриптов. Особенно хорошо было бы, если бы python компилировался в MSIL и мог использовать CLR-сборки, но, как я понял, IronPython поддерживает только 2.7.

Если это невозможно, есть ли какие-то другие скриптовые языки, хорошо интегрирующиеся с CLR (не только на уровне Interop)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В IronPython хотели добавить поддержку Python 3, но Microsoft прекратила поддержку разработки, а главный разраб ушёл в другую компанию. Так как команды больше нет, то активно развивать IronPython некому. IronPython и IronRuby разработаны за счёт Microsoft, потом у них иссяк интерес к DLR, и они выкинули код в опен-сорс. Последний раз, когда я смотрел, ветка для третьего питона вяло развивалась. Это так, историческая справка.

А теперь к делу. Чем вас не устраивает Python 2.7? Если юникодом, то в IronPython все строки и так юникодовые.

Если вы хотите тесной связи с .NET, то это один из лучших вариантов. Взаимосвязь с .NET полноценная и очень детально проработанная.

Вообще, для .NET реализовано множество языков, включая Ruby, JavaScript и прочие. Но выбирать их из-за того, что Python не нужной вам версии будет, как минимум, странно. В ближайшем будущем всё равно ветка 2.x будет жить. А альтернативные реализации для .NET всё равно не будут поспевать за последними новинками языков, какой бы язык вы ни выбрали.

Я могу понять, если у вас уже есть пласт кода на Python 3 или острая необходимость в новых возможностях третьей версии языка. Но в условиях, когда в приложение просто надо добавить скрипты, ориентиороваться стоит на несколько другие параметры: насколько язык распространён, насколько понятен, насколько хорошо реализована интероперабельность.

Comment: Сейчас есть такая ситуация: есть несколько питон-скриптов, в которые подключены сторонние питон-библиотеки (извините, в Pythone пока разбираюсь посредственно) и есть опасение, что не получится перенести этот питон-код на Iron из-за этих самых библиотек(я вообще так и не понял, можно ли сторонние библиотеки использовать в IronPython)

Comment: @AlexVoskresenskiy Со сторонними библиотеками просто: если в коде только питон, то они будут работать. Если библиотеки прибиты гвоздями к реализации CPython бинарниками (всякие математические библиотеки, например), то работать не будут. Собственно, в той же мере, в какой дотнетовые библиотеки не будут работать в CPython.

Answer (score 2):

По поводу других языков.

1. powershell. Скриптовый язык, который изначально работает в CLR. Отсюда - прозрачная работа с любыми объектами.
2. Сам C#. Режим командной строки, конечно, не поддерживается - но скрипт, находящийся в файле, можно скомпилировать на лету и выполнить.

Comment: Скрипты нам нужны в первую очередь, чтобы их писали и использовали наши алгоритмисты. Для них C# и powershell, все-таки, сложны - идею с C# бросили, когда пытались реализовать на нем "простенький" TCP-Listener в виде скрипта. На Питоне это в разы проще и людей научить можно быстрее, нужно что-то в этом роде

Comment: Э... если алгоритмисту приходится работать с TCP Listener - тут что-то определенно не так. PS а на питоне что, TCP Listener пишется проще? Не верю.

Comment: На питоне они их писали в 40 строк - даже меня впечатлило. Попробуйте написать его асинхронно и с нюансами(например, когда вы опрашиваете мост в COM-порт). C# в таких штуках требует подготовки и сноровки

Comment: PowerShell я бы не советовал, потому что язык хуже интеропится с дотнетом, чем железный питон. Синтаксис у языка вертится вокруг "команд", что приводит к довольно противному коду, если пользоваться языком ради скриптов в приложении. Ну и язык не самый популярный (хоть и не самый сложный, да).

Comment: @PavelMayorov Алгоритмисту приходится работать с такими вещами, потому что они сами делают железки и потом к ним же делают скрипты-обработчики. А мы не можем сделать какого-то "обобщенного" решения - только какие-то готовые кусочки. Вот и не можем придумать удобного "и тем и другим" решения

Comment: Если вы под "асинхронностью" понимаете неблокирующий режим (или, что еще хуже, Begin/End паттерн) - то да, в 40 строк не уложиться. А вот если вспомнить про такую штуку, как `await`... Тут будет больше трудностей с работой с COM-портом, чем с TCP сокетами.

Comment: Писал и на Begin-End(2-3 года назад) и на async/await. Ни то, ни другое человек без познаний в программировании, как мне кажется, нормально написать не может, все-таки C# не "язык для домохозяек". Впрочем, может я просто не нашел готовых решений на шарпе. А вот на питоне оно есть и очень простое и понятное. Да и в целом их язык подкупает и я их в этом понимаю:)

Comment: @AlexVoskresenskiy: Вообще-то, программирование всяких асинхронностей на C# с async/await именно что для домохозяек. Посмотрите на примеры с TcpClient. [Пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/337052/10105).

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл [IronPython](https://github.com/IronLanguages/ironpython3) для третьепитона. Последний коммит 3 месяца назад.

Также можно использовать конвертер [3to2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/3to2) (для того, чтобы преобразовать код Python 3 в код Python 2) и использовать стабильную официальную версию:

`$ pip install 3to2
$ 3to2 manifest_parser.py -w
  ...вывод опущен...
$ python2
  Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:38) 
  [GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
  Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
  ... import manifest_parser`

И никаких исключений

Comment: Я так понимаю, эту ветку production-ready считать нельзя?

Comment: Скорее всего, да. Раз даже релиза ни одного нет...

Comment: @alex-voskresenskiy, добавил вариант с 3to2.

Comment: Спасибо! А как у IronPython обстоят дела с использованием сторонних библиотек (на обычном python)?

Comment: А это я уже не знаю...

Answer (score 0):

Еще вариант:

Использовать отдельно приложение на C# и отдельный процесс на питоне, связь - через SOAP или XML-RPC. Запросы и ответы можно гонять по stdin/stdout, можно по HTTP, можно через MQ...

Достоинство этого метода - априорная возможность использовать ту версию языка, которая кажется наиболее красивой.

Answer (score 0):

И еще вариант связи. Можно основное приложение сделать на питоне, а часть на C# подгружать как библиотеку. Модуль для CPython можно без проблем написать на C++/CLI.