# Проблема с переводом в C#

Tags: c#, python

```
X=[]
Y=[]
# read the training data
with open('spambase.data') as f:
    for line in f:
        curr = 1ine.split(',')
        new_curr = [1]
        for item in curr[:len(curr) - 1]:
            new_curr.append(float(item))
        X.append(new_curr)
        Y.append([f1oat(curr[-1])])
X = np.array(X)
X = preprocessing.scale(X) # feature scaling
```

[Скрин кода](https://sun1-11.userapi.com/c840025/v840025147/82622/T1oyecwFm8E.jpg)

Мне нужно перевести код с Python на С#. Понятия не имею что делать с этой частью кода.

Comment: Не думаю, что перевести код на С# лучшая идея, вам придется реализовать микро сервис  для чтения данных и интегрировать код. Попробуйте использовать другую библиотеку

Comment: @АлексейКлещевников Я понимаю, что идея не из лучших, но , к сожалению, требуется именно перевести код на C#

Comment: Ни разу не интегрировал python и c#, но можете взглянуть https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/9.3.php, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/426929/%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-python-3-%D1%81-c/426934#426934. Удачи

Comment: В общем-то, не понятно только, что делать с функцией preprocessing.scale(X)

Comment: @Mathworld В этом и прикол. Всё, что до `preprocessing.scale(X)` реализуется без проблем. Код пишется за пару минут. А с `preprocessing` проблема больше относится к алгоритмике, чем к написанию кода. С таким вопросом вам нужно отдельно вопрос писать с тегом "алгоритм", а уже по алгоритму пытаться написать реализацию на C#.

Comment: C# умеет IronPython запускать, может это вам подойдет? (Я python не знаю)

Answer (score 0):

Пришлось малость погуглить чтоб выяснить, что значит вот это

```
 X = preprocessing.scale(X)
```

Оказалось, что речь идет о питоновской библиотеке машинного обучения `Scikit-Learn`.
Можно предположить, вы откуда-то взяли пример программы машинного обучения и решили вот таким наивным образом путем "тупого перевода" с одного языка на другой что-то там реализовать. Я вас расстрою, это так не работает. На мой взгляд, у вас 3 возможных реальных сценария дальнейших действий:

1) взять готовую библиотеку типа [Accord.NET Framework](http://accord-framework.net/index.html) вдумчиво почитать документацию, скачать и посмотреть примеры, а потом написать свое приложение;

2) воспользоваться вот таким портом [Sharpkit.Learn - Machine Learning library for .Net (C#, F#)](https://github.com/foreverzet/Sharpkit.Learn), опять же ознакомиться с доками и потом попробовать "прикрутить" его к своему проекту;

3) попытаться написать самому только **обёртку на C#** в виде вызовов и чтения выходных данных над этой программой написанной на python.

Выбор за вами.