# Client Server обмен сообщениями

Tags: c#, .net, консоль

Всем привет! Есть

**Сервер:**

```
TcpClient tcpclient = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
 NetworkStream nstream = tcpclient.GetStream();
 StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(nstream, Encoding.UTF8) { AutoFlush = true };
 StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(nstream, Encoding.UTF8);

 while (true)
 {
     string inputline = "";
     while (inputline != null)
     {
         inputline = reader.ReadLine();
         Console.WriteLine("Клиент написал: " + inputline);
     }
```

**и Клиент:**

```
TcpClient client = new TcpClient("localhost", port);
        NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
        Console.WriteLine("Подключено");
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream) { AutoFlush = true };

        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Введите сообщение: ");
            string lineToSend = Console.ReadLine();
            writer.WriteLine(lineToSend);
        }
```

Как можно с сервера отправить клиенту ответное сообщение, если при старте сервера (даже если принимаем клиента в новом потоке) полностью блокируется ввод сообщения в консоли сервера? Т.е. мы можем только отправлять сообщения на сервер, а ответ с сервера клиенту писать не можем.

Comment: Можно либо делать чтение и запись в разных потоках, либо использовать асинхронное чтение, не блокирующее поток.

Comment: Что значит «отправить»? Вы хотите отправить ответ автоматически, или ввести его с клавиатуры? Если автоматически, так просто посылайте его после приёма. Да, и клиент, разумеется, должен _слушать_ ответ.

Comment: Отправлять с консоли сервера, ответ клиенту автоматически я сделал.

Comment: @Regent а вы не могли бы показать как организовать на моем примере чтение в разных потоках?

Comment: Ну, после `inputline = reader.ReadLine();` дописываете `writer.WriteLine("answer");`. А вообще, лучше делать асинхронно, как [здесь](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/337052/10105).

Comment: Асинхрония для меня пока не подходит, хотелось бы просто выделить в отдельные потоки и понять как это все действует как у меня на примере, можете помочь?

`writer.WriteLine("answer");` автоматический ответ я сделал, но мне надо вручную писать клиенту с сервера

Comment: @Regent если у вас есть ответ - оформляйте его как ответ с кодом. а не как коммент со ссылкой в fiddle.

Comment: @Regent это плохая схема. Она не дает другим пользователям голосовать до того, как автор сказал "это правильно", т.е. автор должен полагаться только на свое мнение в выборе правильного ответа (а у него обычно не хватает компетентности). Если автор выберет другое решение как правильное, то ваш код просто пропадет (даже если он в разы лучше выбранного, тут такое сплошь и рядом) - а суть системы ответов SO в том, чтобы хорошие ответы поднимались вверх *даже* если топикастер выбрал другой ответ.

Comment: @Regent ну и [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/) если уж на то пошло :)

Comment: @Malcolm: Не совсем понимаю тогда. Вы пишете, что ответ сервера вводить с консоли не нужно, но в вопросе пишете «если при старте сервера (даже если принимаем клиента в новом потоке) полностью блокируется ввод сообщения в консоли сервера». Ну так наплюйте на консоль, чем это мешает?

Comment: @PashaPash так ведь дело ещё и в том, что другие пользователи могут голосовать не только плюсами, но и минусами, имея своё мнение. А так как за репутацией я не гоняюсь, то с такими успехами можно и в ноль уйти. Меня сегодня весь день печалит, что я не могу на русском SO редактировать вопросы сразу, равно как и голосовать за закрытие вопроса. За https://dotnetfiddle.net/ спасибо, а то я со своим jQuery и не уходил дальше http://jsfiddle.net  :)

Comment: @Regent Ваш вариант годится лучше всего в организации нового потока, вопрос как его запустить в новом потоке через Thread, я так понимаю в таком случае и клиента нужно будет принимать в новом потоке?

Comment: В принципе видимо расклад состоит так: **Слушаем клиента в бесконечном цикле в новом потоке -> организуем прием от клиента сообщений в бесконечном цикле в новом потоке -> и организуем ответ клиенту в бесконечном цикле в новом потоке.** Теперь вопрос: Как?

Comment: Я просто им  не разу не пользовался, привык к Thread, да действительно все работает, но вот что странно, когда с сервера отправляешь клиенту сообщение, то пока клиент не ответит на него сервер не дает написать следующее и наоборот.

Comment: @Regent да все верно можете выставлять реализацию вашего кода, как ответ, отмечу решенным в синхронном приложении.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сервер (2 потока, один для обработки запросов от клиента, другой для обработки запросов с консоли):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    TcpListener tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 4000);
    tcpListener.Start();
    Console.WriteLine("Сервер запущен");
    TcpClient tcpclient = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
    NetworkStream nstream = tcpclient.GetStream();
    Console.WriteLine("Клиент подключен");
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(nstream, Encoding.UTF8) { AutoFlush = true };
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(nstream, Encoding.UTF8);
    new Thread(() =>
    {
        while (true)
        {
            string inputline = reader.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Клиент написал: " + inputline);
            writer.WriteLine(inputline.Length);
        }
    }).Start();
    new Thread(() =>
    {
        while (true)
        {
            string lineToSend = Console.ReadLine();
            writer.WriteLine("Инфо: " + lineToSend);
        }
    }).Start();
}
```

Клиент (2 потока, один для обработки консоли и отправки данных серверу, другой для обработки полученных от сервера данных):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Подключение к серверу...");
    int port = 4000;
    TcpClient client = new TcpClient("localhost", port);
    NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
    Console.WriteLine("Подключено");
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream) { AutoFlush = true };

    new Thread(() =>
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Console.Write("Введите сообщение: ");
            string lineToSend = Console.ReadLine();
            writer.WriteLine(lineToSend);
            Console.WriteLine("Сообщение отправлено");
        }
    }).Start();

    new Thread(() =>
    {
        while (true)
        {
            string inputline = reader.ReadLine();
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            Console.WriteLine(inputline);
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
        }
    }).Start();
}
```

Comment: Единственное что хочу попросить, проверьте клиента, по такой схеме он запускается подключается и сразу закрывается, не пойму почему [вот реализация](https://dotnetfiddle.net/EY4kQD)

Comment: Нашел причину `Console.ReadLine();` в конец всего кода, вот только если зациклить, то опять клиент несет какаю то чушь, т.е. становится синхронным.

Comment: @Malcolm всё переписал в VS, с использованием Thread, у меня сейчас работает.

Comment: Скинь исходник пожалуйста.

Comment: @Malcolm [сервер](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wZjrP2) и [клиент](https://dotnetfiddle.net/j4cSoj).

Comment: А как к примеру теперь запускать клиента в новом потоке?

Comment: Пытался сделать что то типа [этого](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KSfMp5) - не вышло.

Comment: да да да именно, я вот мучаюсь с примером, не могу понять как загнать подключившегося клиента в новый поток, именно на Вашем примере. Так как тут можно подключить только одного клиента.

Comment: Вот тут я не подумал, можно добавить клиентов в **<List>** и там оперировать с ними.

Comment: @Malcolm вообще говоря, это уже тянет на отдельный вопрос, но да ладно. Доработанный код сервера находится [тут](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IsUYf3). Идея в том, что `.AcceptTcpClient()` находится в бесконечном цикле, и каждому клиенту выделяются свои потоки со своими `StreamWriter` и `StreamReader`. Сообщение из консоли рассылается всем клиентам из списка. Код по-прежнему сделан без обработки ошибок и прочего - просто как наглядный пример идеи.

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Все работает как часы, последняя к Вам просьба, я не могу грамотно отключить клиента, если подключиться и закрыть окно консоли клиента, то сервер сообщает о том что не может прочитать поток, и отваливается. И еще, как с вами можно связаться?

Comment: @Malcolm достаточно обернуть всю работу с клиентом в `try - catch`. По-хорошему, в `catch` стоит закрывать и `StreamReader`, и `StreamWriter`, чтобы память не утекала. Я сделал пример, в котором закрывается только `writer`. [Код тут](https://dotnetfiddle.net/QDNaYf). А зачем со мной связываться?

Comment: Может мне придется когда нибудь обратиться за помощью, а здесь выйдет так что не получится, поэтому желательно бы иные источники.

Comment: @Malcolm спору нет: на русскую версию SO я переключился только сегодня, но свободного времени на помощь у меня весьма мало,  поэтому удобнее пользоваться всё тем же SO (вполне возможно, что помочь сможет кто-то другой гораздо раньше меня), чем дожидаться, когда я вообще появлюсь где-либо.

Comment: а `Reader` попытался закрыть [так](https://dotnetfiddle.net/b88KAo). Но тогда сервер снова не может писать клиенту.

Comment: @Malcolm проблем я вижу две: 1. В `readers` ничего не добавляется. 2. `foreach` в `foreach` - неправильный подход. Цикл должен быть только по `writers`, а в случае ошибки и закрытия должны браться текущий `writer` и **соответствующий** ему `reader`. Чтобы взять соответствующий `reader`, нужно либо надеяться, что он расположен в `readers` на том же месте, что и `writer` в `writers`, либо сделать `reader` и `writer` полями одного объекта (нового класса с условным именем `MyClient`) и использовать везде уже `List<MyClient> clients`

Answer (score 1):

пусть сервер распределяет сообщения между клиентами. Тогда у сервера не будет консоли, и соответственно проблемы тоже.
Если сервер обязан вести лог, то тогда нужен объект синхронизации lock.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/c5kehkcz.aspx

Comment: Нет лог мне не нужен, просто желательно сделать как сказано выше, чтение и запись в отдельных потоках, вот только как я не знаю.

Comment: Ну сделай после Console.WriteLine("Клиент написал: " + inputline); сразу Console.ReadLine() и отправь клиенту. А у клиента reader.readLine()

Comment: Вроде работает только вот одно но, если с сервера отправить клиенту сообщение, то сервер ждет ответа от клиента и не дает написать следующее, и наоборот

Comment: Мотомучто приложение синхронное. Вам нужно использовать асинхронную реализацию. А главном потоке крутить ввод/вывод консоли, а в других потоках получение сообщений с сокета