# Передача фото по TCP

Tags: c#, tcp

У меня меня есть сервер которые принимает разного рода команды, и мне нужно сделать так, чтобы я мог еще отправлять фото. Я пытался делать что-то вроде такого: сперва кодировал изображение и в начале добавлял `<IMAGE>`, чтобы сервер понял, что это изображение и вот тут все проблемы и пошли, никак это не получается сделать. А еще надо узнать имя пользователя, кто отправил это изображение. Как этого достичь?

P.S. клиент пишется не на C#, так для информации.

**UPDATE:**

Код сервера:

```
public static void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    String content, sData, _sData = String.Empty;
    byte[] bData = { };

    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();

    // Retrieve the state object and the handler socket
    // from the asynchronous state object.
    StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
    Socket handler = state.workSocket;

    // Read data from the client socket. 
    int bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);

    if (bytesRead > 0)
    {
        state.sb.Append(Encoding.GetEncoding(866).GetString(state.buffer, 0, bData.Length));
        content = state.sb.ToString();

        Console.WriteLine(content);

        if (content.IndexOf("<FILE_SEND>") > -1)
        {
            memoryStream.Write(bData, 0, bData.Length);
            file_send = false;

            if (content.IndexOf("<FILESEND>") > -1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Good");
                Stream fileStream = new FileStream(@"C:\output.jpg", FileMode.Create);

                memoryStream.Position = 0;
                fileStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
                memoryStream.CopyTo(fileStream);

                fileStream.Close();
                memoryStream.Close();

                memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                Send(handler, content);

            }
            else
            {
                handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Not all data received. Get more.
            handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
            new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
        }
    }
}`
```

Не обращай внимая как я раскодирую текст, там просто код вырезан..
Ну вот проблема даже не в кодировке, а в том как правильно получать эти данные, чтобы кроме передачи фото, работали команды такого вида `user get USER_NAME` и т.д.

Comment: Покажите код своего сервера, хотя бы релевантную часть.

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Comment: Думаю вовремя передачи изображения к пакетам лучше добавлять хедер с uuid который сгенерил клиент. а этот uuid  уже к клиенту где-то в базе привязать.

Comment: 1. [сериализация](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F). 2. [comparison of data serialization formats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_data_serialization_formats).

Comment: Можно пример насчет uuid?
Про серилизацию данных знаю что это, вопрос был в другом.

Comment: Проще использовать WCF и не парится с голым TCP/IP

Comment: Посмотрите сюда, тут более человеческий пример: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/337052/10105

Comment: Та, там работа с самим сервером, но пример, очень даже не плохой. Так я в другом никак ни могу разобраться, как мне команды и файлы принимать, хочется чтобы все это было в одной программе

Comment: Посмотри на WCF http://blogs.quovantis.com/large-file-streaming-using-wcf/

Comment: У меня есть библиотека для обмена строками. http://infostart.ru/public/525806/

Comment: @HackMemory: Смотрите. Я бы для начала разработал формат передачи. Например, такой. (1) длина строки (4 байта), (2) строка с командой (3) содержимое, в зависимости от команды. Если команда = image, то (3а) длина имени пользователя, (3б) имя пользователя, (3в) длина данных картинки, (3г) данные картинки. Если команда другая, то и хвост другой. И лучше всего не пользоваться cp866, а только unicode (utf-8 или utf-16, как вам удобнее).

Comment: Делал так для проверки пока, сперва объединяю `<IMAGE>`, с частью картинки, да забыл сказать, данные отправляются частями, то есть 1024 байтов за раз. Ну вот объединяю, и отправляю, и на сервере, проверяю есть ли слово `<IMAGE>`, если да, то он будет принимать данные, как бы все хорошо, но часть данных пропадает, точнее пропадают в нем кириллица, в картинке она присутствует и это все пока в локалке, что будет на сервере не представляю. Я для шифрования использовал base64 encode. Я когда еще хотле использовать GZip, но там какая то проблема с магическими символами, не понял в чем беда

Comment: Данные могут приходить одновременно такого вида `°±Ііґµ¶·ё№є»јЅѕїАБВГДЕЖЗИЙКЛМН`
То есть есть и кириллица и латиница, и как избежать потерю данных?

Comment: Ладно тогда вопрос в другом, как правильно или лучше кодировать данные? Чтобы при раскодировики не терялись данные?

Comment: вы все усложняете в очень простой задаче. *Выделите отдельный транспортный слой*, который любые переданные ему данные упакует в пакет "длина->данные". На другой стороне этот пакет раскроют и передадут данные выше тому, кто знает как их разбирать. Транспортный слой не знает, что он передает - его дело передать. Поэтому для него все есть байты и можно даже контрольную сумму в пакет класть. Ну  а после того как данные полученные равны отправленным, то и доставайте из данных что вам надо, как будто и не было никакой передачи.

Answer (score 1):

Я использую для обмена с 1С обмен через строки с упаковкой данных
[Использование ТСД на WM 6 как беспроводной сканер с получением данных из 1С](http://infostart.ru/public/525806/)

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Sockets;
namespace TCPConnectTo1C
{
    public class  ДляОбменаПоТСП
    {
        public static readonly  Encoding CurrentEncoder=Encoding.GetEncoding(1251);

       public static  byte[] РасжатьДанные(byte[] массивДанныхДляКоманды)
        {
            var memStream = new MemoryStream(массивДанныхДляКоманды);
            var DecompressStream = new MemoryStream();
            using (GZipStream gzipStream = new GZipStream(memStream, CompressionMode.Decompress, false))
            {

                Byte[] buffer = new Byte[1 << 16];
                int h;
                while ((h = gzipStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    DecompressStream.Write(buffer, 0, h);
                }
            }
            return DecompressStream.ToArray();
        }

        public static byte[] СжатьДанные(byte[] Value)
        {
            var memStream = new MemoryStream();
            memStream.Position = 0;
            using (GZipStream gzipStream = new GZipStream(memStream, CompressionMode.Compress))
            {
                gzipStream.Write(Value, 0, Value.Length);
                gzipStream.Flush();
            }
            return memStream.ToArray();


        }
        private static byte[] МассивБайтовИзСтрима(NetworkStream стрим, int размерМассива)
        {
            byte[] result = new byte[размерМассива];
            int количествоСчитанныхСимволов = 0;
            while (размерМассива > количествоСчитанныхСимволов)
            {
                количествоСчитанныхСимволов += стрим.Read(result, количествоСчитанныхСимволов, размерМассива - количествоСчитанныхСимволов);
            }

            return result;
        }

        public static void ЗаписатьМассивБайтовВСтрим(NetworkStream стрим, byte[] Массив)
        {

            стрим.Write(Массив, 0, Массив.Length);
        }

        public static bool ReadBool(NetworkStream стрим)
        { 
            return BitConverter.ToBoolean(МассивБайтовИзСтрима(стрим,1), 0);
        }

        public static void Write(NetworkStream стрим, bool Value)
        {
            ЗаписатьМассивБайтовВСтрим(стрим, BitConverter.GetBytes(Value));

        }
        public static Int32 ReadInt32(NetworkStream стрим)
        { 
            return BitConverter.ToInt32(МассивБайтовИзСтрима(стрим,4), 0);
        }

        public static void Write(NetworkStream стрим, Int32 Value)
        {
            ЗаписатьМассивБайтовВСтрим(стрим, BitConverter.GetBytes(Value));

        }
        public static string ReadString(NetworkStream стрим)
        {
         int РазмерДанных=ReadInt32(стрим);
         if (РазмерДанных == 0) return "";
            var данные=МассивБайтовИзСтрима(стрим,РазмерДанных);

            return CurrentEncoder.GetString(данные, 0, данные.Length);
        }

        public static void Write(NetworkStream стрим, string Value)
        {
            if (Value.Length == 0)
            {
                Write(стрим, 0);
                return;
            }
            byte[] result = CurrentEncoder.GetBytes(Value);
            Write(стрим, result.Length);
            ЗаписатьМассивБайтовВСтрим(стрим,result);

        }
        public static string ReadCompressedString(NetworkStream стрим)
        {
          //  int РазмерДанных = ReadInt32(стрим);
           // return CurrentEncoder.GetString(МассивБайтовИзСтрима(стрим, РазмерДанных));
            bool ЭтоСжатаяСтрока = ReadBool(стрим);

            if (!ЭтоСжатаяСтрока) return ReadString(стрим);

            int РазмерДанныхДляКоманды = BitConverter.ToInt32(МассивБайтовИзСтрима(стрим, 4), 0);
            byte[] массивДанныхДляКоманды = МассивБайтовИзСтрима(стрим, РазмерДанныхДляКоманды);
            массивДанныхДляКоманды = РасжатьДанные(массивДанныхДляКоманды);
            return CurrentEncoder.GetString(массивДанныхДляКоманды, 0, массивДанныхДляКоманды.Length);

        }

        public static void WriteCompressedString(NetworkStream стрим, string Value)
        {
            if (Value.Length == 0)
            {
                Write(стрим, false);
                Write(стрим, 0);
                return;
            }


            byte[] result = CurrentEncoder.GetBytes(Value);
            var СжатыеДанные=СжатьДанные(result);
            if (result.Length>СжатыеДанные.Length)
            {
            Write(стрим, true);
            Write(стрим, СжатыеДанные.Length);
            ЗаписатьМассивБайтовВСтрим(стрим,СжатыеДанные);
            }
            else
            {
            Write(стрим, false);
            Write(стрим, result.Length);
            ЗаписатьМассивБайтовВСтрим(стрим,result);
            }


        }

        public static void ОтправтьКоманду(NetworkStream strim,string Команда, string ДанныеДляКоманды, bool ЕстьОтвет)
        {
           Write(strim,ЕстьОтвет);
           Write(strim,Команда);
           WriteCompressedString(strim,ДанныеДляКоманды);
        }

        public static void ПринятьКоманду(NetworkStream strim, out string Команда, out string ДанныеДляКоманды, out bool ЕстьОтвет)
        {
           ЕстьОтвет=ReadBool(strim);
           Команда=ReadString(strim);
           ДанныеДляКоманды=ReadCompressedString(strim);
        }
    }
}
```

И отправка

```
bool СоединитьсяССервером()
        {

            try
            {
                if (клиент == null)
                {
                    клиент = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                    клиент.Connect(ipEndpoint);
                }
                return true;
            }
            catch (SocketException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Ошибка соединения с сервером: " + ex.Message);
                клиент.Close();
                клиент = null;
                return false;
            }
        }

        string ОтправтьКоманду(string Команда, string ДанныеДляКоманды, bool ЕстьОтвет, bool ЗакрытьСоединение, out bool ОшибкаСоединения)
        {




            var result = "";
            ОшибкаСоединения = false;
            try
            {

                if (!СоединитьсяССервером())
                {
                    ОшибкаСоединения = true;
                    return "Ошибка";
                }

                using (var strim = new NetworkStream(клиент))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        ДляОбменаПоТСП.ОтправтьКоманду(strim, Команда, ДанныеДляКоманды, ЕстьОтвет);
                        if (ЕстьОтвет) result = ДляОбменаПоТСП.ReadCompressedString(strim);
                    }
                    catch (SocketException ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Ошибка  отправки данных: " + ex.Message);
                        result = "Ошибка";
                        ОшибкаСоединения = true;
                    }

                    if (ЗакрытьСоединение)
                    {
                        клиент.Close();
                        клиент = null;
                    }

                }
            }
            catch (SocketException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Ошибка соединения с сервером: " + ex.Message);
                result = "Ошибка";
                ОшибкаСоединения = true;
            }
```

И на сервере

```
public void ОткрытьАйПиПортСНомеромПорта(int НомерПорта)
        {

            Event = new AutoResetEvent(false);

            ИдПотока = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;

            ЭтоЗакрытие = false;
            Server = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            IPEndPoint ipEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, НомерПорта);
            Server.Bind(ipEndpoint);
            Server.Listen(1);
            Server.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(ОбработкаСоединения), Server);

        }



        public void Ответить(string Ответ)
        {
            Otvet = Ответ;
            Event.Set();

        }

private void ОбработкаСоединения(IAsyncResult AsyncCall)
        {
          Socket listener = (Socket)AsyncCall.AsyncState;
          if (listener == null || (ЭтоЗакрытие)) return;

          Socket client = listener.EndAccept(AsyncCall);
           ВыполнитьКоманду(client);

          listener.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(ОбработкаСоединения), listener);  
        }


private void ВыполнитьКоманду(Socket client)
        {

        NetworkStream стрим=new NetworkStream(client);
        try
        {

            var Данные = ДляОбменаПоТСП.ПринятьКоманду(стрим);

            Event.Reset();

            if (ПришлоСообщениеПоTCP!=null)
                     ПришлоСообщениеПоTCP(Данные);

            if (Данные.ЕстьОтвет)
            {

                Event.WaitOne();
                ДляОбменаПоТСП.WriteCompressedString(стрим, Otvet);


            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ЗаписатьОшибку(DateTime.Now.ToString() + e.ToString());

        }
        }
```

Проект можно посмотреть здесь https://yadi.sk/d/G1FvJW_Ytfc5X

Comment: Ну так вот, я использовал GZip как ты, ну вот когда я получаю уже сжатые данные, и пытаюсь разжать, то у меня выскакивает исключение, о каких то магических символов или что то вроде этого. Не знаю в чем может быть причина

Comment: У меня этот код работает еще с WinCE

Comment: Добавил ссылку на проект https://yadi.sk/d/G1FvJW_Ytfc5X