# Visual C#, Передача файлов по локальной сети, Сокеты, передаётся только 256 байт

Tags: c#, сокеты

Есть проект для передачи файлов по сети. Файл передаётся, но передаётся только размером 256 байт, а дальше передача не продвигается. Подскажите пожалуйста в чём причина.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;
//using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows;

namespace Peredacha
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        String IP;
        int combo;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //Создаем поток для приема сообщений
            new Thread(new ThreadStart(Receiver)).Start();
            new Thread(new ThreadStart(FileReceiver)).Start();
        }
        //Метод потока
        protected void Receiver()
        {
            //Создаем Listener на порт "по умолчанию"
            TcpListener Listen = new TcpListener(7000);
            //Начинаем прослушку
            Listen.Start();
            //и заведем заранее сокет
            Socket ReceiveSocket;
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    //Пришло сообщение
                    ReceiveSocket = Listen.AcceptSocket();
                    Byte[] Receive = new Byte[256];
                    //Читать сообщение будем в поток
                    using (MemoryStream MessageR = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        //Количество считанных байт
                        Int32 ReceivedBytes;
                        do
                        {//Собственно читаем
                            ReceivedBytes = ReceiveSocket.Receive(Receive, Receive.Length, 0);
                            //и записываем в поток
                            MessageR.Write(Receive, 0, ReceivedBytes);
                            //Читаем до тех пор, пока в очереди не останется данных
                        } while (ReceiveSocket.Available > 0);
                        //Добавляем изменения в ChatBox
                        ChatBox.BeginInvoke(AcceptDelegate, new object[] { "Получаю: " + Encoding.Default.GetString(MessageR.ToArray()), ChatBox });

                    }
                }
                catch (System.Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }

            }
        }

        //Метод потока
        protected void FileReceiver()
        {
            //Создаем Listener на порт "по умолчанию"
            TcpListener Listen = new TcpListener(6999);
            //Начинаем прослушку
            Listen.Start();
            //и заведем заранее сокет
            Socket ReceiveSocket;
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    string name;
                    //Пришло сообщение
                    ReceiveSocket = Listen.AcceptSocket();
                    Byte[] Receive = new Byte[256];
                    //Читать сообщение будем в поток
                    using (MemoryStream MessageR = new MemoryStream())
                    {

                        //Количество считанных байт
                        Int32 ReceivedBytes;
                        Int32 Firest256Bytes = 0;
                        String FilePath = "";
                        do
                        {//Собственно читаем
                            ReceivedBytes = ReceiveSocket.Receive(Receive, Receive.Length, 0);
                            //Разбираем первые 256 байт
                            if (Firest256Bytes < 256)
                            {
                                Firest256Bytes += ReceivedBytes;
                                Byte[] ToStr = Receive;
                                //Учтем, что может возникнуть ситуация, когда они не могу передаться "сразу" все
                                if (Firest256Bytes > 256)
                                {
                                    Int32 Start = Firest256Bytes - ReceivedBytes;
                                    Int32 CountToGet = 256 - Start;
                                    Firest256Bytes = 256;
                                    //В случае если было принято >256 байт (двумя сообщениями к примеру)
                                    //Остаток (до 256) записываем в "путь файла"
                                    ToStr = Receive.Take(CountToGet).ToArray();
                                    //А остальную часть - в будующий файл
                                    Receive = Receive.Skip(CountToGet).ToArray();
                                    MessageR.Write(Receive, 0, ReceivedBytes);
                                }
                                //Накапливаем имя файла
                                FilePath += Encoding.Default.GetString(ToStr);
                            }
                            else

                                //и записываем в поток
                                MessageR.Write(Receive, 0, ReceivedBytes);
                            //Читаем до тех пор, пока в очереди не останется данных
                        } while (ReceivedBytes == Receive.Length);
                        //Убираем лишние байты
                        String resFilePath = FilePath.Substring(0, FilePath.IndexOf('\0'));
                        using (var File = new FileStream(resFilePath, FileMode.Create))
                        {//Записываем в файл
                            File.Write(MessageR.ToArray(), 0, MessageR.ToArray().Length);
                        }//Уведомим пользователя
                        ChatBox.BeginInvoke(AcceptDelegate, new object[] { "Получено: " + resFilePath, ChatBox });
                        name = resFilePath;
                    }
                /*   DataRow workRow = bD1DataSet.Tables[0].NewRow();//BD1DataSet1.Tables[0].NewRow();
                    workRow["id"] = 1;
                    workRow["data"] = System.DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString();
                    workRow["time"] = System.DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
                    workRow["nazv"] = name;
                    bD1DataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Add(workRow);
                    this.Validate();
                    this.ipadressBindingSource.EndEdit();
                    this.tableAdapterManager1.UpdateAll(this.bD1DataSet);*/
}
                catch (System.Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }

            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Отправляет сообщение в потоке на IP, заданный в контроле IP
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="Message">Передаваемое сообщение</param>
        void ThreadSend(object Message)
        {
            try
            {
                //Проверяем входной объект на соответствие строке
                String MessageText = "";
                if (Message is String)
                {
                    MessageText = Message as String;
                }
                else
                    throw new Exception("На вход необходимо подавать строку");

                Byte[] SendBytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(MessageText);
                //Создаем сокет, коннектимся
                IPEndPoint EndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(IP), 7000);
                Socket Connector = new Socket(EndPoint.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                Connector.Connect(EndPoint);
                Connector.Send(SendBytes);
                Connector.Close();
                //Изменяем поле сообщений (уведомляем, что отправили сообщение)

                ChatBox.BeginInvoke(AcceptDelegate, new object[] { "Отправлено " + MessageText, ChatBox });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

        }

        //Делегат доступа к контролам формы
        delegate void SendMsg(String Text, RichTextBox Rtb);

        SendMsg AcceptDelegate = (String Text, RichTextBox Rtb) =>
        {
            Rtb.Text += Text + "\n";
        };

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            IP = comboBox1.Text;
            Ping ping = new Ping();
            PingReply reply = ping.Send(IP);
            if (reply.Status != IPStatus.Success)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Не удаётся подключиться!");
                button2.Enabled = false;
            }
            else {
                button2.Enabled = true;
                //Отправляем файл
                //Добавим на форму OpenFileDialog и вызовем его
                if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    //Коннектимся
                    IPEndPoint EndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(IP), 6999);
                    Socket Connector = new Socket(EndPoint.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                    Connector.Connect(EndPoint);
                    //Получаем имя из полного пути к файлу
                    StringBuilder FileName = new StringBuilder(openFileDialog1.FileName);
                    //Выделяем имя файла
                    int index = FileName.Length - 1;
                    while (FileName[index] != '\\' && FileName[index] != '/')
                    {
                        index--;
                    }
                    //Получаем имя файла
                    String resFileName = "";
                    for (int i = index + 1; i < FileName.Length; i++)
                        resFileName += FileName[i];
                    //Записываем в лист
                    List<Byte> First256Bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(resFileName).ToList();
                    Int32 Diff = 256 - First256Bytes.Count;
                    //Остаток заполняем нулями
                    for (int i = 0; i < Diff; i++)
                        First256Bytes.Add(0);
                    //Начинаем отправку данных
                     System.IO.FileInfo file = new System.IO.FileInfo(openFileDialog1.FileName);
                      long size = file.Length;
                    Byte[] ReadedBytes = new Byte[256];
                    using (var FileStream = new FileStream(openFileDialog1.FileName, FileMode.Open))
                    {
                        using (var Reader = new BinaryReader(FileStream))
                        {
                            Int32 CurrentReadedBytesCount;
                            //Вначале отправим название файла
                            Connector.Send(First256Bytes.ToArray());
                            do
                            {
                                //Затем по частям - файл
                                CurrentReadedBytesCount = Reader.Read(ReadedBytes, 0, ReadedBytes.Length);
                                Connector.Send(ReadedBytes, CurrentReadedBytesCount, SocketFlags.None);
                            }
                            while (CurrentReadedBytesCount == ReadedBytes.Length);
                        }
                    }
                    //Завершаем передачу данных
                    Connector.Close();

                }



            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // переместить на клавишу отправки связать с progressBar
           // System.IO.FileInfo file = new System.IO.FileInfo(openFileDialog1.FileName);
          //  long size = file.Length;
           // MessageBox.Show(size.ToString()); // для проверки вывода размера файла
            new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(ThreadSend)).Start("Получение"); //otpravka
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: данная строка кода позволяет загрузить данные в таблицу "bD1DataSet.dannie". При необходимости она может быть перемещена или удалена.
            this.dannieTableAdapter.Fill(this.bD1DataSet.dannie);
            // TODO: данная строка кода позволяет загрузить данные в таблицу "bD1DataSet.ip_adress". При необходимости она может быть перемещена или удалена.
            this.ip_adressTableAdapter.Fill(this.bD1DataSet.ip_adress);

        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            panel2.Visible = false;
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String stro;
            combo = comboBox1.Items.Count;
            combo = combo + 1;
            stro = IP1.Text + "." + IP2.Text + "." + IP3.Text + "." + IP4.Text;
            bD1DataSet.Tables[1].Rows.Add(combo, textBox1.Text, stro);
            this.Validate();
            this.ipadressBindingSource.EndEdit();
            this.tableAdapterManager1.UpdateAll(this.bD1DataSet);
            panel2.Visible = false;
            panel1.Visible = true;
        }

        private void добавитьКомпьютерToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            panel1.Visible = false;
            panel2.Visible = true;
            panel3.Visible = false;
        }

        private void посмотретьВсеКомпьютерыToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Form2 f = new Form2();
            //f.Show();
            panel3.Visible = true;
            panel1.Visible = false;
            panel2.Visible = false;
            dannieDataGridView.Visible = false;
            ip_adressDataGridView.Visible = true;
            bindingNavigator1.Visible = true;
            bindingNavigator2.Visible = false;
        }

        private void button3_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            panel2.Visible = false;
            IP1.Text = ""; IP2.Text = ""; IP3.Text = ""; IP4.Text = "";
            textBox1.Text = "";
        }

        private void IP1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String a;
            int f;
            a = IP1.Text;
            try
            {
                f = int.Parse(a);
                for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
                {
                    if (f == i) { a = i.ToString(); }
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                if (IP1.Text != "") { MessageBox.Show("Не верный символ!"); IP1.Text = ""; }
            }
        }

        private void IP2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String a;
            int f;
            a = IP2.Text;
            try
            {
                f = int.Parse(a);
                for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
                {
                    if (f == i) { a = i.ToString(); }
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                if (IP2.Text != "") { MessageBox.Show("Не верный символ!"); IP2.Text = ""; }
            }
        }

        private void IP3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String a;
            int f;
            a = IP3.Text;
            try
            {
                f = int.Parse(a);
                for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
                {
                    if (f == i) { a = i.ToString(); }
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                if (IP3.Text != "") { MessageBox.Show("Не верный символ!"); IP3.Text = ""; }
            }
        }

        private void IP4_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String a;
            int f;
            a = IP4.Text;
            try
            {
                f = int.Parse(a);
                for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
                {
                    if (f == i) { a = i.ToString(); }
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                if (IP4.Text != "") { MessageBox.Show("Не верный символ!"); IP4.Text = ""; }
            }
        }

        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            panel3.Visible = false;
            panel2.Visible = false;
            panel1.Visible = true;
        }

        private void посмотретьФайлыToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            panel3.Visible = true;
            panel1.Visible = false;
            panel2.Visible = false;
            dannieDataGridView.Visible = true;
            ip_adressDataGridView.Visible = false;
            bindingNavigator1.Visible = false;
            bindingNavigator2.Visible = true;
        }

        private void bindingNavigator1_RefreshItems(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void panel3_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void progressBar1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button6_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            panel3.Visible = false;
            panel2.Visible = false;
            panel1.Visible = true;
        }

        private void comboBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: может причина в том, что вы сами в коде ограничились 256 байтами?

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/311128/

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/548764/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be-tcp/548934#548934

Answer (score -1):

Попробуй вместо

```
Byte[] ReadedBytes = new Byte[256];
```

поставить `File.ReadAllBytes(path)`

```
Byte[] ReadedBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
```

Ну и на примем так же

Comment: Путь, как я понимаю путь к файлу. В отправке написал я через OpenDialog. В А что писать файла приём?