# Асинхронный сервер не принимает данные после отправки первого пакета

Tags: c#, сокет, async-await, асинхронность

```
namespace LoginServer {
    public class ClientData
    {
        public IPAddress _IP;
        public int _Port;
        public byte[] _Key;

        public ClientData(IPAddress IP, int Port)
        { _IP = IP; _Port = Port; }

        public ClientData(int Port)
        { _Port = Port; }

        public void Clear()
        {
            _IP = IPAddress.None;
            _Port = 0;
            _Key = new byte[] { 0x00 };
        }
    }

    public partial class fgen : Form
    {
        private TcpListener listener;
        NetworkStream stream;
        private static StringBuilder msg = new StringBuilder();

        ClientData[] cd = new ClientData[256];

        private byte[] PrepareToSend(byte[] opkode, byte[] send)
        {
            int len = send.Length + 4;
            byte[] Out = new byte[len];
            byte[] size = BitConverter.GetBytes(len);
            Array.Copy(size, Out, 2);
            Array.Copy(opkode, 0, Out, 2, 2);
            Array.Copy(send, 0, Out, 4, send.Length);
            return Out;
        }

        private byte[] PrepareToRead(byte[] read)
        {
            int len = read.Length - 2;
            byte[] Out = new byte[len];
            try
            {
                Array.Copy(read, 2, Out, 0, len);
            }
            catch (System.ArgumentException e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
            }
            return Out;
        }

        private int AddClient(IPAddress IP, int Port)
        {
            //Это точно новый клиент?
            ClientData data;
            for (int i = 0; i < cd.Length; i++)
            {
                data = cd[i];
                if (data != null)
                {
                    if (data._IP == IP && data._Port == Port)
                    {
                        //Нет. Вернем его номер в массиве
                        return i;
                    }
                }
                else
                    break;
            }
            //Да
            for (int i = 0; i < cd.Length; i++)
            {
                data = cd[i];
                //Если не юзалось
                if (data == null)
                { 
                    cd[i] = new ClientData(IP, Port);
                    //Вернем номер записи в массиве
                    return i;
                }
                //Ищем пустое место
                if (data._IP == IPAddress.None && data._Port == 0)
                {
                    //Пустое место. В него и запишем
                    cd[i] = new ClientData(IP, Port);
                    //Вернем номер записи в массиве
                    return i;
                }
            }
            return -1;
        }

        async public Task LoginStart()
        {
            listener = TcpListener.Create(current_server_info.LoginServer_Port);
            listener.Start();
            msg.Clear();
            msg.AppendFormat("Сервер запущен.");
            Trace.WriteLine(msg.ToString());
            sstat.Text = "запущен (порт: " + current_server_info.LoginServer_Port + ")";
            while (true) // тут какое-то разумное условие выхода
            {
                TcpClient Client = await listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
                /*await*/ OnConnect(Client); // await не нужен
            }
        }

        async Task OnConnect(TcpClient c)
        {
            msg.Clear();
            msg.AppendFormat("Клиент {0} подключился\n", c.Client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());
            Trace.Write(msg.ToString());
            IPAddress cIP = ((IPEndPoint)c.Client.RemoteEndPoint).Address;
            int cPort = ((IPEndPoint)c.Client.RemoteEndPoint).Port;
            int now = AddClient(cIP, cPort);
            if (now == -1)
            {
                log.AppendText("Ошибка во время добавления или поиска клиента!!!\n");
                return;
            }
            await Work(c, now);
        }

        public async Task Work(TcpClient c, int n)
        {
            stream = c.GetStream();
            //Получим сообщение от клиента
            byte[] buf = await ReadFromStreamAsync(stream);
            msg.AppendFormat("Получил от {0}: {1}\n", c.Client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString(), BitConverter.ToString(buf));
            Trace.Write(msg.ToString());
            if (buf[0] + buf[1] > buf.Length)
            {
                //Пакет недошел
                log.AppendText("Ошибка во время приема данных.\n");
                c.Client.Disconnect(false);
                c.Client.Dispose();
            }
            //Обрежем размер (первые 2 байта)
            buf = PrepareToRead(buf);

            //Обработка сообщения клиента
        }

        async Task<byte[]> ReadFromStreamAsync(NetworkStream stream)
        {
            byte[] size = new byte[2];
            await stream.ReadAsync(size, 0, 2);
            int n = size[0] + size[1];
            byte[] buf = new byte[n];
            buf[0] = size[0];
            buf[1] = size[1];
            var readpos = 2;
            while (readpos < n)
                readpos += await stream.ReadAsync(buf, readpos, n - readpos);
            return buf;
        }
    } }
```

Есть такой код, взят и немного модифицированный с [этой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/336949/%D0%90%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-tcp-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80) темы. При подключении клиента все ок, при отправке клиентом первого пакета тоже все ок. Но дальше просто не принимает данные. Клиент отправляет, проверил через WPE, а сервер ничего не делает. Кто-то что-то знает по тому поводу))?

Comment: Ну так у вас метод `Work` после обработки первого сообщения ничего и не делает. Странно было бы, если б что-то происходило.

Comment: @VladD И что мне добавить в метод Work чтобы он возвращался в прослушивание и получал новые данные)?