# Удалённое взаимодействие с пк с#

Tags: c#, tcp

Я хочу сделать так.
есть две программы(**на разных пк**), у одной есть кнопка при нажатие на которую отправлялся **event(пакет)** другому пользователю, тот получал этот я **event** у него удалялась программа с пк,Удаление и всё остальное я могу сделать сам,но без понятия как сделать между ними соединение, **без открытых портов** и при **постоянно меняющимся ip.**

Answer (score 2):

> без открытых портов

Эт, батюшка, так не выйдет. Это как разговаривать находясь в разных городах **без включенной техники** -- НИКАК.

В любом случае нужно будет использовать некий порт для прослушки сигнала.

> и при постоянно меняющимся ip

А вот это будет немного сложнее. Нужно будет обьявить серверную сторону и клиентскую.

Клиент находит сервер в локальной сети

> она же локальная, надеюсь?

по хостнейму(имени) компьютера и там уже они обмениваются пакетами. Как делать связь клиент-сервер можно почитать вот здесь: [Асинхронный Tcp клиент-сервер](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/336949/%D0%90%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-tcp-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80) или поискав по стековерфлоу или в интернете в принципе.